# How to send some logs from windows kernel driver to serial port in VMware and get it on host machine

Tags: windows, serial-port, kernel, driver, vmware-workstation

I want to send some logs from windows kernel driver (in VMWare) to host machine via COM Port, How can we achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Kernel debug the windows machine over serial, then add regular debug prints to your code. If necessary, enable the prints in the guest machine and/or configure the debugger to show them.

Comment: I have my own driver running in VMWare windows 10, so I want its log via serial port to host machine, although I can use DbgPrint but in this case I need to use serial communication from VM to host.

Comment: I understood the question and the answer I gave is good. Another possible solution is to write to the serial port in the guest and read from it on the host, but I don't have step-by-step instructions for that.